# Why does ping require the setuid bit?

Tags: file-permissions, raspberry-pi, setuid

In the Jessie version for the Raspberry Pi, `ping` requires the `setuid` bit to be set.  What is the rationale for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ping needs to generate and receive ICMP packets, and usually that's done using "raw sockets" – a feature limited to root (cap_net_raw) because it could also be abused to sniff and disrupt other traffic on the system.

Many distributions now just give ping the *cap_net_raw* privilege (see `capabilities(7)` and `getcap(8)` manual pages) instead of full setuid root. This however needs both the kernel and the filesystem to support extended attributes (xattrs), and some "minimal" systems disable those.

Also, recently a special ["ICMP" socket type](https://lwn.net/Articles/420799/) was added that allows sending ICMP Echo messages only, without any additional privileges. The ping command hasn't been updated for it yet though.

Comment: i think capabilities(7) doesn't use xattrs.

Comment: @ggg: But it does. Try `getfattr --dump --match=.* /sbin/ping`.